# Use of arXiv tags

Tags: discussion, tags

When MathOverflow began we decided to start using [arXiv classification](http://arxiv.org/archive/math) and created corresponding tags. These are still the most broadly used tags on MathOverflow. However, the usage of some these tags differs slightly from the arXiv description, so it's unclear what we should put in the tag wikis.

I see three main options:

1. Revert to the original arXiv descriptions.
2. Keep the tag names but use our own descriptions that match our usage.
3. Discard the arXiv names and use our own names with our own descriptions.

Comment: Oh, so _that's_ why the tag names have prefixes. I like option #2 -- tag excerpts get shown while looking for tags to enter, a short  description(instead of a list) is helpful. (However, I can see the advantage of using lists of subtopics)

Comment: I started copying arXiv descriptions for common tags since that's already an improvement over nothing at all. Apparently, I can only do a few per day, so that will take a while...

Comment: re:few-per-day:Huh? You're a moderator, this should not be rate limited.  re:improvement: I agree. The question is, do we just keep it like that or add more improvements? Also, any objections to me doing the same if you are rate limited?

Comment: Apparently there should not be any X-tag-wiki-edits-per-day restriction for mods (I checked with Shog9). If you encounter it, please report it in the Teacher's Lounge or as a bug on meta.

Comment: You're right, I was blocked by a pending edit but I had to click a few random things before I could see it.

Comment: OK. Took care of the top ones. My cut & paste skills are tired now...

Comment: No probs, I'll do a few more if I get time.

Comment: I am still in favor of keeping the tag names as they are ([the discussion over tea](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1380/arxiv-tags-was-cs-arxiv-tags/)). A small distinguishable set of classification tags is essential (at least for me).   
Btw, don't forget that you can now define tag synonyms. :)

Comment: I also like option #2.

Comment: This is not completly on-topic here, I originally wanted to ask a separate question, but decided on quickly asking you here: it seems to me *at the moment* these tags are nowwhere documented. By contrast on the old MO they were very prominent on the Ask Question page. The "nowhere" is more for the documentation discussion, but I'd like to know something else: do you know if we could (at least in principle) get the current text 'in the tag box' while it is empty changed to mention them?