# Help cleanup tags!

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, faq-proposed

This is meant to agglomerate tags that need (occasional or regular) cleanup. That is tags that mean multiple unrelated things and need to be separated into more specific tags. Please follow the examples below and discuss specific needs in comments or separate questions, as necessary.

Conversely, some subjects are scattered over several tags and there it might make sense to merge some tags and to create synonyms. Proposals for such can also be added as answers.

As of August 8, 2017, the length limit for tags went from 25 characters to 35 characters. So now is a great time to allow inconveniently compressed tag names to stretch out a bit...

---

PS: If you want to cleanup these tags, please keep your rate down to a few posts per day so that your edits don't clutter the main page. Also note that merges can be done by moderators in one go without bumping questions. Thus, it is usually better not to carry out significant merges manually. (Here, "significant" means about four or more. Ask for moderator advice if you need to go beyond that.)

Comment: Can you simply delete all tags that have < x followers, where x is a positive integer the moderators set?

Comment: @Bill: That would delete a lot of seldom used tags, which is not the intent here.

Comment: Maybe not, François, but it would help to delete these tags.

Comment: @BillJohnson, another objection is simply that many people don't use the 'favorite' and 'ignored' system, but tags are still useful to them. I don't think there's any guarantee that every "interesting-to-someone" tag is actually a 'favorite' of anyone.

Comment: I completely agree with @BillJohnson that there are too many tags and I think we should try to get rid of quite a number of them. One could discuss what is the best way to go about this, but that there are too many tags for me is a given. (And I write this as someone who actually read the pages over pages of tags, more than once.)

Comment: By the way, is there a particular reason why MO uses its own classification of subjects in mathematics rather than a tag system along the lines of the MSC (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/msc2010.html)?

Comment: @StefanKohl MO uses the (simpler) [arxiv classification](http://arxiv.org/archive/math).

Comment: Only a small part of the tags are actually arxiv tags. -- The arxiv classification doesn't go very much into detail, which is -- besides the easiness of creating new tags -- probably the reason for the many additional tags, including tags with unclear meaning and outright 'clutter tags' (though some of the latter have been removed in the course of the thread http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/642/tags-that-encourage-off-topic-questions).

Comment: @StefanKohl: Yes, feel free to ask for the deletion of some clutter tags. (It's best to ask a question on meta since a some users like to assist in cleanup efforts.)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: I think the main point are not single inappropriate tags. Contrary to the top-level arxiv categories, the MSC is already fully-thought reasonably complete standard classification, and I think adopting it for MO would probably remove the need to think about adding or removing tags, about which tags are appropriate and which are not and about which tag means what. Or do you see a reason for MO's partial reinvention of the wheel here?

Comment: @StefanKohl: Users are able to create their own tags. The system was [seeded with arxiv tags](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1/ignore-this-question) to get things going but there was no long-term plan to keep them. The main problem with MSC is that it's too large.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: Sure, there are 4 or 5 times as many 5-digit MSC numbers than tags in MO -- but contrary to MO tags, the MSC is an hierarchical scheme. Thus if e.g. using two of the three levels is sufficient for MO, one could well restrict to that.

Comment: @StefanKohl: I agree but it's unlikely to change. See this [old discussion](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1380/arxiv-tags-was-cs-arxiv-tags/).

Comment: @StefanKohl, one problem with MSC numbers is that they are unintuitive numbers and so except for the ones I use frequently, I would not recognize most of them.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Of course displaying just the numbers would be pretty bad. -- But every MSC number has a text attached to it, and that (or some shorthand in case it is long) might be displayed as a tag.

Comment: @StefanKohl, the OP would still need to look up the code before posting.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: actually, they wouldn’t need to!  The auto-complete system here is clever enough that if a tag is called e.g. “54-XX-general-topology”, it will be suggested when you start typing “topology”.  Honestly, that would give a better lookup interface for the MSC than the current official ones…

Comment: The question is used more generally than described. I updated the description to reflect current usage.

Answer (score 10):

The tags [lattices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/lattices) and [lattice-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/lattice-theory) are (unsurpsingly) used for both the 'order' and the 'geometric' meaning.

(I am not sure what to do here; perhaps it deserves a full question, but I thought I'd post here first to get some initial reaction.)

Comment: There was an old discussion on tea about this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I should have known/checked. Yet, while in some sense there were even two: in the very old  http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/679/lattices/ Ryan Budney suggested upon Mariano mentioning the problem, to have lattice-poset and lattice-subgroup In http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1375/disambiguating-the-tag-lattices/ the issue is somewhat different as I think in that request the order meaning was ignored and the issue was distinguishing between really geometric objects and more algebraic things (vaguely), and there is euclidean-lattice for the former.

Comment: Oh I forgot to finish my idea... While the subject came up there was not much discussion and/or they were somewhat inconclusive (regaridng the matter I have in mind) except for Ryan's (IMO, good) idea that never got implemented though.

Comment: For this, we should fix the terminology everywhere in mathematics, not only on the MathOverflow website.  Also, let's fix "field" too while we're there.

Comment: @ZsbánAmbrus what do you want to express precisely?

Answer (score 9):

The tag [gaussian](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gaussian) is mainly used for questions in a probability context but there are some other "Gaussian" things in there too, e.g., Gaussian binomial coefficients, Gaussian integers.

Perhaps, the current tag [gaussian](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gaussian) should be renamed to something more specific, like gaussian-distributions or gaussian-variables or something along these lines (not sure, suggestions welcome). And the (few) existing ones where it then does not fit could be retagged.

Note there is also a tag [gaussian-elimination](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gaussian-elimination).

Comment: Is the dv against the renaming or against the tag being reserved for the prob context. Or against still something else. In any case it would somehow help the discussion if such things where communicated else it is anybodies guess what is the intent.

Answer (score 9):

There is a [built-in system](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/synonyms) to automatically create tag synonyms by the nomination and voting of high-reputation users.  Unfortunately, it appears that hardly anyone ever looks at this page (and the qualifications for voting are fairly demanding), so I'm posting it here to try to get it more attention.  In particular, all of the synonyms marked as "pending" are languishing in neglect until they get four people (or a moderator?) to vote for them, though I think some of them are going the wrong direction.

Comment: It might be worth adding that to vote one needs to (at least I think so) click on the left tag of the two to get to its page where the voting possibility is.

Comment: There is no way to discuss the synonyms suggested through this system, or is there?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek for all I know, no.  If you do not approve of one, you can downvote it, and if it reaches score -2  (or something like this) it is deleted.

Answer (score 8):

The tags [matrix-analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/matrix-analysis) (32 questions tagged) and [matrix-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/matrix-theory) (18 questions) should probably be merged, unless there is a strong difference between them that I am not aware of (incidentally, there is also [matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/matrices), 150 questions tagged).

The tag [matrix-inverse](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/matrix-inverse) (6 questions) seems overly specific and in my opinion it should be removed outright.

Comment: There is also [tag:matrix-equations] but there is no [tag:matrix-algebra]. I don't know what the differences could be; I hope somebody will explain. Are these tags used in significantly different ways?

Comment: The ones I have heard in real life are: "matrix analysis" for the study of matrix inequalities and advanced linear algebra (e.g. [[1]](http://www.amazon.com/Matrix-Analysis-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387948465)); matrix functions and matrix equations (mostly numerical/applied; e.g. [[2]](http://www.mims.manchester.ac.uk/events/workshops/FUN13/)). "matrix algebra" is not that common and typically used by non-mathematicians. "matrix theory" sounds strange to my ear.

Comment: My suggestion is as follows: make [tag:matrix-theory] a synonym of [tag:matrix-analysis]; I could consider merging them both into [tag:matrices], although that's a bit generic; Stet [tag:matrix-equations], remove [tag:matrix-inverse]

Comment: re matrix-theory: I think this is an instance of a sort of general MO phenomenon, users add 'theory' to distinguish it from just the 'thing' that is perhaps too generic as a tag; we had some discussion on order-theory. For some q tagged matrix-theory it seems matrix-analysis would not fit. One could go over the list though and extract these things relatively quickly. For matrix-inverse, I am in favor of getting rid of it yet via a *synonym*, else people will recreate it, or even worse use just [tag:inverse] which should also be listed here in fact.

Comment: There are also various other tags containing matrix and matrices some *very* little used. Would you have an opinion on some more of them?

Comment: Personally I'd keep [tag:matrices], [tag:random-matrices], [tag:matrix-analysis], [tag:nonnegative-matrices], [tag:matrix-equations] and maybe [tag:sparse-matrices]. I don't know what [tag:r-matrix] refers to; if it's short for "random matrix" then merge. [tag:m-matrix] and [tag:copositive-matrix] can be merged into [tag:nonnegative-matrices]. [tag:adjacency-matrices] and [tag:matrix-tree] into some variant of [tag:graph-theory] I guess (not an expert). [tag:nilpotent-matrices], [tag:circulant-matrices], [tag:orthogonal-matrices] seem too specific.

Comment: We should look for more opinions though, there are surely lots of other people with different viewpoints than mine on "matrix stuff".

Comment: Thanks. This looks good to me. The tag [tag:r-matrix] was created for something called "R-matrix" in quantum algebra/groups (I don't know what it is though). It was misused a bit though. I think/hope I 'cleaned' it just now, and it is just this qa thing now, which one might keep (but I cannot tell); preferably with a tag-wiki so it does not get used again for dealing with matrices in the software R...   For matrix-tree this is uniquely used and not even very relevant where it is used, I would simply remove it; for adjacency-matrix one could set up a synonym into [tag:algebraic-graph-theory]

Comment: Also talking about matrices, @FrançoisG.Dorais now that we have sysnonyms could you please set up the synonym matrices <--- matrix I think there is some risk of people not finding the tag due to the (unusual) plural.

Comment: @quid: When a tag doesn't exist, I don't think I have a quick way to create a synonym so it's just as easy for you to suggest it as it is for me.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais oh, I was not aware of this, and I have to confess the fact that I can suggest syns did not really sink in either. I will try it some time soon and in the meantime voted on the syn. But also, while in this case it is true I could have suggested it, this is not always the case as a user (besides globally enough points) needs some  score (namely 5) in the tag.

Comment: A recent post [suggesting to synonymize matrix-theory and matrices](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/194/help-improve-tagging/5546#5546).

Answer (score 8):

> As of August 8, 2017, the length limit for tags went from 25 characters to 35 characters. So now is a great time to allow inconveniently compressed tag names to stretch out a bit...

Perhaps we could collect here list of tags which now, after the character limit for length of tag name has been extended, could be spelled in full instead of a shortening. (This answer is CW - feel free to edit in here various tags that are currently shortened.)

Among possible suspects are the tags with name of length 25 - they can be found by this SEDE query: [Tags with given length of name](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/708452/tags-with-given-length-of-name?length=25). (However, not all shortened tags use exactly 25 characters. Two examples are [computational-group-theo](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/computational-group-theo) or [infinite-dim-manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/infinite-dim-manifolds).)

**Shortenings to be expanded**

- [gch](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gch) vs. [generalized-continuum-hypothesis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/generalized-continuum-hypothesis) (Both names should be kept here with a synonym in one or the other direction. After all, people around here know what GCH is, so it probably can remain the master tag. But adding a synonym might be useful addition, since people looking for the tag corresponding to their might start to write something liked "continuum hypothesis" in the tag field.)
- [dg-categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/dg-categories) $\to$ [differential-graded-categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/differential-graded-categories) (Maybe the shortened name could be kept as synonyms - since MO users are probably used to it by now?)

**Shortening which moderators already replaced**

- [stochastic-diff-equations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/stochastic-diff-equations) $\to$ [stochastic-differential-equations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/stochastic-differential-equations)
- [supercuspidal-repr](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/supercuspidal-repr) $\to$ [supercuspidal-representations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/supercuspidal-representations)
- [cartesian-closed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/cartesian-closed) $\to$ [cartesian-closed-categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/cartesian-closed-categories)
- [classical-invariant-theor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/classical-invariant-theor) $\to$ [classical-invariant-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/classical-invariant-theory)
- [combinatorial-group-theor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/combinatorial-group-theor) $\to$ [combinatorial-group-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/combinatorial-group-theory)
- [combinatorial-hopf-algebr](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/combinatorial-hopf-algebr) $\to$ [combinatorial-hopf-algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/combinatorial-hopf-algebras)
- [combinatorial-number-theo](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/combinatorial-number-theo) $\to$ [combinatorial-number-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/combinatorial-number-theory)
- [combinatorial-optimizatio](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/combinatorial-optimizatio) $\to$ [combinatorial-optimization](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/combinatorial-optimization)
- [computational-group-theo](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/computational-group-theo) $\to$ [computational-group-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/computational-group-theory)
- [computational-number-theo](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/computational-number-theo) $\to$ [computational-number-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/computational-number-theory)
- [derived-algebraic-geometr](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/derived-algebraic-geometr) $\to$ [derived-algebraic-geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/derived-algebraic-geometry)
- [differential-galois-theor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/differential-galois-theor) $\to$ [differential-galois-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/differential-galois-theory)
- [differential-graded-lie-a](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/differential-graded-lie-a) $\to$ [differential-graded-lie-algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/differential-graded-lie-algebras)
- [infinite-dim-manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/infinite-dim-manifolds) $\to$ [infinite-dimensional-manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/infinite-dimensional-manifolds)
- [infinite-time-computabili](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/infinite-time-computabili) $\to$ [infinite-time-computability](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/infinite-time-computability)
- [modular-rep-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/modular-rep-theory) $\to$ [modular-representation-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/modular-representation-theory)
- [multiplicative-number-the](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/multiplicative-number-the) $\to$ [multiplicative-number-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/multiplicative-number-theory)
- [probabilistic-number-theo](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/probabilistic-number-theo) $\to$ [probabilistic-number-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/probabilistic-number-theory)
- [pseudo-differential-opera](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/pseudo-differential-opera) $\to$ [pseudo-differential-operators](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/pseudo-differential-operators)
- [symmetric-monoidal-catego](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/symmetric-monoidal-catego) $\to$ [symmetric-monoidal-categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/symmetric-monoidal-categories)
- [transcend.-number-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/transcend.-number-theory) $\to$ [transcendental-number-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/transcendental-number-theory)<sup>1</sup>

**Synonyms with names longer than 25 characters**

- [differential-graded-algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/differential-graded-algebras) $\to$ [dg-algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/dg-algebras)
- [topological-quantum-field-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/topological-quantum-field-theory) $\to$ [tqft](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/tqft)
- [unique-factorization-domains](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/unique-factorization-domains) $\to$ [ufds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ufds)

<sup>1</sup>There is a separate discussion whether there could be a better name for this tag: [The tags (transcendence) and (transcendental-number-theory)](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3044).

Comment: As I was not sure how to "expand" ([tag:combinatorial-hopf-algebr]), ([tag:differential-graded-lie-a]) and ([tag:infinite-time-computabili]), I'm leaving suggestions for this tag to users who are more familiar with these areas.

Comment: In case it is useful for somebody, here is query for tags with [length at least 20](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/708458/tags-with-tagname-of-lenght-at-least?length=20). (Of course, you can easily change 20 and 25 to other numbers.)

Comment: We have a tag ([tag:cartesian-closed]). With a longer character limit, we could have ([tag:cartesian-closed-categories]). Was this the intended meaning of this tag? Or is *cartesian closed* commonly used also in some other meanings?

Comment: BTW (topological-quantum-field-theory) fits the new 35 characters limit. Would maybe a synonym ([tag:topological-quantum-field-theory]) $\to$ ([tag:tqft]) make sense. (It might help people to find the tag, if they start typing "topological quantum field theory" in the tags field when asking a question.)

Comment: Actually I think that [tag:gch] should be made a synonym to [tag:continuum-hypothesis], and the usage guidance the latter can obviously encompass the generalized one. And "*people around here know what GCH is*": no, I know quite many people in pure math who would not identify "GCH" without further context.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest deleting the tag [decomposition-theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/decomposition-theorem).

I would guess that the tag was intended to be about the decomposition theorem of Beilinson-Bernstein-Deligne-Gabber. It seems unnecessary to have a whole tag just dedicated to this theorem ([perverse-sheaves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/perverse-sheaves) should suffice). What's worse, most posts with this tag are just about various "decompositions" in any area of mathematics.

Comment: Do you think that (perverse-sheaves) tag should be added to some of the posts which are tagged [decomposition-theorem but not preverse-sheaves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/decomposition-theorem+-perverse-sheaves)? I have asked a moderator (Todd Trimble) about this tag [not too long ago](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2018/4/26). Since he suggested simply removing (decomposition-theorem), after the removal some of those questions might be missing the relevant tag.

Comment: Hi Martin. I took a look and there are two questions on that list related to the BBD decomposition theorem and perverse sheaves: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128822/ and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1039/ . I guess those two could be retagged but I wouldn't consider it urgent (they have other accurate tags).

Answer (score 5):

**[Done](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/233412/revisions)** (suggested Feb. 2016, done March 2016)

I propose to deprecate [abstract-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra). It seems redundant with other tags, very broad, and the usage seems inconsistent.

I feel it is comparable to the meanwhile removed [topology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/topology) and the deprecated [geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/geometry).

(Explication on terminology: To deprecate a tag is not a technical measure. What it means is that the tag-description is changed to say this tag should no longer be used. Over time it could then be slowly phased out via retagging.)

---

**Not (yet?) done** (YCor Feb 01, 2020): I'd suggest to *blacklist* and *burninate* [abstract-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra). This tag exists in about 270 questions, including about 15 in the last 2 years (probably it was written many more times in spite of being deprecated, but has been often replaced or removed by users like me or Martin Sleziak. Actually, there was about 17 questions with the *only* tag [abstract-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra), and I've systematically retagged these questions, so at this time there should be none. Also I've browsed this list and questions almost at least another reasonable tag (I've retagged a few exceptions, when the other tags were meta/ non-specific/ narrow).

Comment: @YCor Regarding your recent edit: The same suggestion was posted here (basically without any response): [The existing deprecated tags should be blacklisted](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3718).

Comment: Actually I meant burninate as well, which wasn't part of the linked question. Burninate and blacklist seem to be quite disjoint facts since one concerns the past and the other concerns the future. Taking care of posts with a single tag was obviously having in mind burnination.

Answer (score 5):

A tag called [field-with-one-element](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/field-with-one-element) with one element was [created recently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62652842#62652842). At the same time, there already exists a tag called [f-1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/f-1). (Currently with 66 questions.)
Since both of them refer to [field with one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element), I suppose that it would be reasonable to create a synonym between them (in one direction or the other).

I have brought this up in chat and [one of the moderators suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62667797#62667797) that it would be reasonable to post on meta first - to see whether somebody is opposed to this suggestion.

I will add a link to the [whole conversation in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/conversation/the-tags-f-1-and-field-with-one-element).

Comment: Either `field-with-one-element` or `one-element-field` is much clearer than `f-1` (which always makes me think of race cars).

Comment: I think *"field with one element"* is more common and I agree it's more clear than the cryptic "f-1".

Comment: I have now merged [f-1] into [field-with-one-element]

Answer (score 4):

The tags [noncommutative-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/noncommutative-algebra) and [noncommutative-rings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/noncommutative-rings) should be merged; the first being more used, and also in analogy with the tag [ac.commutative-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ac.commutative-algebra), I'd suggest to embed [noncommutative-rings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/noncommutative-rings) into [noncommutative-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/noncommutative-algebra).

Making a synonym [noncommutative-rings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/noncommutative-rings) $\to$ [noncommutative-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/noncommutative-algebra) would also have the advantage that the latter tag is suggested when people type "ring".
(Note: [commutative-rings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/commutative-rings) has already been embedded in [ac.commutative-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ac.commutative-algebra).)

Comment: Re: *does not include the word "ring" in its wiki, and hence is not suggested when people type "ring".* In fact, the tag-wiki does not influence whether the tag is shown when you type something in the tag field. This is influenced only by tag names (including tag synonyms).

Comment: @MartinSleziak right, thanks. Btw the edited tag-wiki for noncommutative-algebra now mention rings, but this means that it will be suggested from typing rings only when they'll be made synonyms.

Comment: I have edited your post to correct the information saying when the tag is suggested. (And to some extent also to make your post shown if somebody views the last activity in the question.) When you have time, please do edit the post further to get it to the form you are satisfied with.

Comment: I've never been convinced about this one and it's been nearly a year. It's still not clear what to do here.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais it's also unlikely that anybody might suggest anything more convincing to you if you don't say why you're not convinced.

Comment: They both have tag descriptions and they don't match: one explicitly includes non-associative algebras and the other explicitly includes commutative rings. It seems somebody thinks the two are slightly different.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais it guess just means that these tags were written by two different persons without comparing to the other one

Comment: Just for the convenience of the people who stumble upon this post, I will mention that there is now a separate question about these two tags: [Noncommutative rings/algebra tags](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4080).

Comment: @MartinSleziak yes of course you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The tag [crystals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/crystals) seems to be used for three completely different meanings: 1) Quantum groups/representation theory/combinatorial crystals 2) [Crystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_(mathematics)) in algebraic geometry/category theory 3) Crystals in physics/condensed matter.

I'm not sure what would be the best way to separate these. Perhaps "crystal-bases" or "crystal-graphs" for 1 and create a bigger tag "quasicrystals" to include 3?

Comment: These are only 30 questions and could thus be done manually by regular users. "crystal-bases" sounds fine for 1; for 2 maybe "crystals-in-categories" (but better suggestions would be useful), for 3 "crystals-quasicrystals"? it's important that the latter tag is proposed if "crys" is typed (it wouldn't if the tag is "quasicrystals").

Comment: To start with, we could rename those in (1) and (3) and wait a bit to be sure how to rename those in (2)

Comment: @YCor In the same spirit as crystals-quasicrystals, I was thinking of the option crystals-isocrystals for 2.

Comment: Actually we could start with renaming 1 and 3 ("crystals-and-quasicrystals" for 3 in coherence with usual syntax) and then ask some feedback from users in the field.

Answer (score 4):

Suggesting to make [characteristic-p](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/characteristic-p) a synonym of [positive-characteristic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/positive-characteristic). Both exist with with 232 questions and 82 questions (and only 7 tagged both). The first one has a tag excerpt. In practice, I can't even detect the beginning of a difference between the two.

I believe the second one ([positive-characteristic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/positive-characteristic)) is slightly better (in principle allowing rings, with positive possibly non-prime characteristic), also has no math symbol with an implicit meaning (namely $p$). Still I'd be OK with the reverse synonym too.

Comment: I will point out that the tag synonym (positive-characteristic) $\to$ (characteristic-p) has been previously suggested by LSpice and is among the pending tag synonyms waiting for votes: https://mathoverflow.net/tags/characteristic-p/synonyms https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1178483/data-about-a-tag-synonym?tagname=positive-characteristic https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1239539/pending-tag-synonyms

Comment: Thanks. I can't upvote it because I need 5 answer rep on this tag. This automatized synonym tag suggestion system is totally inefficient, it will probably still be pending in 2050 if no moderator makes the job...

Answer (score 3):

**[Done](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/230820/revisions)**

I propose to deprecate [discrete-mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/discrete-mathematics). It seems redundant with other tags, very broad, and the usage seems inconsistent.

I feel it is comparable to the meanwhile removed [topology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/topology) and the deprecated [geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/geometry).

(Explication on terminology: To deprecate a tag is not a technical measure. What it means is that the tag-description is changed to say this tag should no longer be used. Over time it could then be slowly phased out via retagging.)

Answer (score 3):

About tag [hyperkaehler](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/hyperkaehler) (13 questions at this date).

a) tautological part: should be changed to [hyperkahler](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/hyperkahler), in coherence with the use of tags related to Kähler: [kahler-manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/kahler-manifolds), [kahler-differentials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/kahler-differentials)...

b) a bit less important: I think it should even be changed, in coherence with the use of [kahler-manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/kahler-manifolds), to [hyperkahler-manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/hyperkahler-manifolds). At least, I've checked all 13 questions and all are compatible with using [hyperkahler-manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/hyperkahler-manifolds).

Comment: Actually [tag:kahler-geometry] and [tag:hyperkahler-geometry] would be even better, since it's more suitable for both considering (hyper)Kähler manifolds, or (hyper)Kähler metrics on a given manifold...

Answer (score 3):

The tag [ft.factorization-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ft.factorization-theory) was created in 2016 by a user who did almost the totality of the 23 questions with it. It is formatted as a top-level tag, while it isn't. Could it be changed to [factorization-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/factorization-theory)?

This tag has empty tag info, seems to be concerned with the multiplicative monoid in rings and factorization question therein. Although it's not very clear to me what it's exactly (and doubt about usefulness of a tag used by a single user on a subject that is broader), I think the existence of this tag is harmless. But shouldn't be disguised as top-level tag.

---

Added: the use of "-theory" seems to make it appear like an well-established field, while I guess it's not the case for "factorization" which deals with some natural factoring problems in ring or semigroup theory. (Of course I consider such a notion as UFD well-established, but it's one specific instance and in any case the tag is not used in questions about UFDs).

For comparison, a quick view of tags with " -theory" (see [the list of tags with 'theory'](https://mathoverflow.net/tags)). It includes the top-level tags [gr.group-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gr.group-theory), [nt.number-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/nt.number-theory), [rt.representation-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/rt.representation-theory), [category-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/category-theory) and a few more, including less used [sp.spectral-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/sp.spectral-theory), [it.information-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/it.information-theory) (the latter comes from the computer science arXiv). Among the main non-top-level tags, it appears in widely used [graph-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/graph-theory), [measure-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/measure-theory), [set-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/set-theory); let me mention as sample a few less used but still over 100 questions such as [matroid-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/matroid-theory), [descriptive-set-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/descriptive-set-theory), [conformal-field-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/conformal-field-theory). These subjects often are documented by textbooks, including more specific ones such as [arakelov-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/arakelov-theory). In a few cases the '-theory' might oversell the subject, or denote a not clearly defined subject (for one instance of the latter is [algebraic-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/algebraic-theory): actually it should be [algebraic-theories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/algebraic-theories) in such case since the tag is about these theories as mathematical objects, rather than as mathematical field— by the way it seems to be entirely captured by [universal-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/universal-algebra) but this is too much of a digression). We should pay particular attention when such tags are created).

---

Added: I realized while adding the previous paragraph that [ft.factorization-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ft.factorization-theory) disappeared (was burninated?) and was replaced with [factorization-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/factorization-theory).

Comment: Since some users reading this might not know the terminology *top-level tag*, I will add these two links: [Why are MO tags formatted as they are?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1457) and [Frequently asked questions about tagging on MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075#1076). I have also [pinged the tag-creator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2020/5/2) to make them aware of the discussion on meta.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for informing me about this discussion on meta. No doubt that factorization theory should *not* have a top-level tag. But concerning the use of "-theory", I beg to disagree: Please search for "Factorization" at https://www.commalg.org/surveys/. For a relatively long time, this area of research has been viewed as a marginal subfield of commutative algebra, as it used to be almost entirely focused on cancellative commutative monoids (the primary source of examples being integral domains). But the situation has sensibly changed in recent years.

Comment: @SalvoTringali thanks for your feedback. Please consider creating tag info as you consider this tag as important. Tag excerpt is the most visible and has the main guidelines (maybe check a few existing ones). Tag wiki can include some more info such as link, book reference.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [invariant-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/invariant-theory) and [classical-invariant-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/classical-invariant-theory) be made synonyms. Don't see the point in making a distinction here.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to make [infinite-sequences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/infinite-sequences) (62 questions as of now) a synonym of [sequences-and-series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series) (1458 questions). I see no usefulness to distinguish them, and the drawback of not gathering basically the same kind of questions (especially given the existence of more specific tags such as [integer-sequences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/integer-sequences)).

Answer (score 3):

We have tags for both [software](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/software) and for [mathematical-software](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/mathematical-software). Some questions are tagged with both. I propose these be merged. Please comment if you disagree!

Comment: Since this is MathOverflow, non-mathematical software is mostly off-topic. I can think of a few exceptions, they should have their own specific tags, with tag info indicating where to go for general help that is not relevant to MO.

Answer (score 2):

**Done.**

The tags [locally-presentable-categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/locally-presentable-categories) and [presentable-categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/presentable-categories) should surely be synonyms.  I would personally prefer that the former (much older, well-established, and less ambiguous, terminology) be the tag and the latter the synonym, but either direction of synonym would be better than having two separate tags.

Comment: For context: [tag:locally-presentable-categories]: 14 questions; [tag:presentable-categories]: 10 questions.

Comment: It is probably the synonym mentioned in this answer was proposed and users with sufficient score in the tag can [vote for (or against) this synonym](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/locally-presentable-categories/synonyms). (The synonym needs score 4 to be approved.)

Answer (score 2):

I propose to make [qcqp](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/qcqp) (10 questions) a synonym of [quadratic-programming](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/quadratic-programming) (34 questions).

[quadratic-programming](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/quadratic-programming) has no usage guidance.

[qcqp](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/qcqp) has: *A quadratically constrained quadratic program (QCQP) is an optimization problem in which both the objective function and the constraints are quadratic functions.*

The latter could be embedded, possibly improved, as usage guidance to the former.

A tag with initials is, I think, not suitable and should systematically be proscribed. (Typing *quadratic* as a tag does not suggest qcqp, which is a problem... and a tag is supposed to convey information to other people than its bare users.)

Hence, if there are serious reasons not to make synonyms, [qcqp](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/qcqp) should be renamed; [qc-quadratic-programming](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/qc-quadratic-programming) would be a compromise. Of course I prefer the previous option (make a synonym).

More generally, I'd propose to systematically rename each tag reduced to initials (please add examples if you can think of), or to the name of a software (I'll ask a [separate question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4148/14094) for the latter).

---

Edit: given Rodrigo de Azevedo's feedback, I suggest to rename [qcqp](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/qcqp) as [q-constrained-quadratic-programming](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/q-constrained-quadratic-programming) (the whole [quadratically-constrained-quadratic-program](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/quadratically-constrained-quadratic-program) exceeds the 35-character limit (43 characters); [q-constrained-quadratic-programming](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/q-constrained-quadratic-programming) is exactly 35).

Comment: Re: *More generally, I'd propose to systematically rename each tag reduced to initials.*  Several suggestion on expanding tags to longer names are [collected in this answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/862/help-cleanup-tags/3340#3340) - moest of those have already been done.

Comment: BTW I have [pinged the tag creators](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2019/3/4) of those two tags - in case they have something to add to this discussion.

Comment: About acronym tags, I always thought that [meta-tag:tags] stands for "Tags And General Stuff".

Comment: I created the QCQP tag. I do not see how it makes any sense to make QCQP and QP synonyms. They are very different. The feasible region of a QP is a convex polytope or an affine space. The feasible region of a QCQP can be a finite set of points. However, I agree that "qcqp" is not easy to find and I would certainly not object to renaming it "qc-quadratic-programming" (if the tag is not too long for MO).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks; I edited accordingly.

Comment: This is a tough one. A priori, I think it's a bad idea to shorten the first word to just "q"; I'd rather have the second, third or later words abbreviated since it's hard to imagine anyone would want to autocomplete "q-" this way. @RodrigodeAzevedo any thoughts?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Much belatedly, how about "quadratically-constrained-qp"?

Comment: Or "quadradrically-constrained-quad-prog"?

Answer (score 2):

I propose to systematically rename each tag [xxx](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/xxx) reduced to the name of a software, adding "-software" to make the tag (thus [xxx-software](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/xxx-software)) more understandable, and, furthermore, to allow to gather such tags when typing "software".

This applies to [sage](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/sage), [gap](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gap), [magma](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/magma), [coq](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/coq), etc (this list is not comprehensive; this post is community-wiki hence feel free to complete it).

If for some reason "software" could be replaced by a better word, please propose. Might be [xxx-programming](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/xxx-programming) or [xxx-program](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/xxx-program) too, I don't know.

Comment: Makes sense but, to play devil's advocate, is there any general confusion going on? Yes, magma is also a math term but this is only one.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais "gap" is a math term ("spectral gap", "gap between primes"). But I didn't talk of confusion. It would be an improvement because "coq-software" would make the meaning of the tag transparent also to people who never heard of coq, and because of another reason I already wrote.

Comment: I hear that and it makes sense to me. I'm inclined to go ahead but I'll let is sit for a few days in case a counterargument comes up.

Answer (score 2):

[continuity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/continuity) seems to have no coherent use. It has 3 watchers for 88 questions, which is a very low ratio (compared to tags [with a comparable number of questions](https://mathoverflow.net/tags?page=12&tab=popular)).

It's mostly to mean some use of continuity, often somewhere fitting with [real-analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/real-analysis), [gn.general-topology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gn.general-topology), and others. This number of questions is ridiculously small compared to the number of questions where the word "continuous" appear ($\ge 11000$), or "continuity" ($\ge 2000$).

Therefore, I'd suggest to deprecate, and even to burninate.

Comment: Do you have a good deprecation message to suggest?

Comment: I will just point out that your second paragraphs suggests that the tag would help find posts which are *about* continuity - as opposed to finding posts where continuity is merely mentioned. (Of course, only if the tag was actually used consistently. I have expanded this a bit [here in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/conversation/usefulness-of-tag-vs-frequency-of-keyword).) This is intended more as a general remark - I do not have strong opinion about this specific tag on MathOverflow in either direction.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais By "deprecation message" you mean the [tag warning](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2798/tag-warnings-on-mo) which would be displayed when somebody attempts to use the tag?

Comment: @MartinSleziak having a quick look at the 50 first questions tagged [tag:continuity], I'd say that at most 5 discuss continuity as a concept. And 5 is an upper bound, there's not a single one for which I'm sure it qualifies (an example which qualifies, but is not tagged [tag:continuity]: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182300/scott-continuity-sub-additivity).

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais *Deprecated; do NOT use this tag. Instead you could consider real-analysis, gn.general-topology, fa.functional-analysis or related tags*.

Answer (score 1):

The tag [filtrations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/filtrations) has a number of completely different questions.  There's a definition in probability theory, as an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-fields.  There also appears to be some completely different meaning in homological algebra or some other areas (too far from my own for me to understand).

Is this notion worthy of its own tag in any of these cases?  (For probability I don't think filtrations need their own tag; I'd just use [stochastic-processes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/stochastic-processes).)  If so, a more specific tag should be made and an appropriate wiki written.  If not, then perhaps the tag should just be destroyed.

Comment: The probability theory notion and the algebra notion are actually essentially the same (a nested chain of substructures), though in practice the ideas needed to think about the two are pretty much unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might make sense to make [polytopes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/polytopes) a synonym for [convex-polytopes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/convex-polytopes). Although non-convex polytopes are sometimes studied, convex ones are much more prevalent. Also there are only 36 questions tagged "polytopes" while there are hundreds tagged "convex polytopes."

EDIT: In light of comments below, I agree that it makes more sense to do the converse- have [convex-polytopes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/convex-polytopes) be a synonym of the more general [polytopes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/polytopes) or [polyhedra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/polyhedra) tag.

Comment: Occurrences at this date: [tag:polytopes]: 36; [tag:convex-polytopes]: 608; [tag:polyhedra]: 151.

Comment: One problem is that technically speaking, questions about non-convex polytopes do not fit in [tag:convex-polytopes]. Other remark: it seems at first sight that most questions in [tag:polytopes] are concerned with convex polytopes, and so do most in [tag:polyhedra]. (...)

Comment: Hence, I would be inclined to make a single tag, named polyhedra for instance, or polytopes, or polyhedra-and-polytopes. With usage guidance, for instance "*Polyhedra, polytopes, polyhedral cones, etc. Can be used in combination with* [tag:convex-geometry]. **Convex polytopes are the convex hulls of a finite set of points in Euclidean spaces. They have rich combinatorial, arithmetic, and metrical theory, and are related to toric varieties and to linear programming.**" (The sentence in boldface is the current usage guidance for [tag:convex-geometry].)

Comment: I'm not sold on this. That a tag is little used is not a reason for it to be deleted. In this case, what is worth fixing is the confusing overlap. There are two approaches to fix this: put everything in the more general polytope, or create a new more specific tag about non-convex polytopes for the few questions that don't fit the convex polytope tag. I'd like to hear more about about what users of these tags think regarding these two options.

Comment: (Typo in my previous comment: the sentence in boldface is the current usage guidance for [tag:convex-polytopes], not for [tag:convex-geometry]. Sorry for the additional noise.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right place to raise the issue, but I don't really like that [combinatorial-geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/combinatorial-geometry) has been merged with [discrete-geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/discrete-geometry). In my opinion, this is the same (in a smaller scale) as merging combinatorics into discrete mathematics. There are many problems in discrete-geometry that have nothing to do with combinatorics.

Comment: That merger was done on December 15, 2014. We can't undo the merger but we could remove the tag synonym to allow future uses of [tag:combinatorial-geometry]. A test for doing this is to propose a tag info blurb which demonstrates how the two tags are different.

Comment: @Francois So I should propose a tag info for [tag:combinatorial-geometry]? I would write something short and simple, like Combgeo. is the study of combinatorial problems that involve geometry. Btw, how can the description of [tag:discrete-geometry] include that "It is closely related to [...] combinatorial geometry" if the latter is a synonym of the former?

Comment: I'm not sure I can see a problem. For the distinction it's enough to use either the tag "discrete-geometry" or the combination of "discrete-geometry" and "co.combinatorics".

Comment: @YCor Then this should have been done when the merger happened, right? Not to mention that I don't recall seeing anyone ever applying both tags. I also don't think it's good to make people double-tag almost all the time, because a large part (but not all) of discrete geometry is combinatorial geometry.

Comment: @domotorp co.combinatorics is a top-level tag so basically every question pertaining to combinatorics gets this tags (unless it has comprises too many topics, but this concerns a very small minority). Usually when anybody ask such a question without tagging combinatorics, somebody adds the tag. As discrete-geometry, the topic makes the tag natural, and also it is regularly added. Adding another tag which basically is relevant iff two other wider tags are simultaneously relevant, would in practice just increase entropy.

Comment: @YCor I would challenge the statement that every question pertaining to combinatorics gets the tag. Check graph-theory; the majority of the questions doesn't have co-combinatorics: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/graph-theory

Comment: @domotorp some people say that every question in graph theory should also be tagged combinatorics. In any case, a very large majority of these questions would perfectly fit in co.combinatorics

Comment: @YCor That's my point - people still don't label them co.combinatorics, so you also shouldn't expect people to label the ones that have combinatorial-geometry or discrete-geometry.

Comment: I know it's hard to rely on a good labeling and acquainted users can help by editing tags. In any case, in such situation the entropy (I mean the mess) is an increasing function of the number of relevant tags.

Comment: @YCor and domotorp: This is (to some extent) related to discussion about ([tag:graph-theory]) and ([tag:co.combinatorics]): [Which “non-arxiv” tags are de facto top-level tags?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3447) Of course, if we strictly follow the guidelines pointed out on MathOverflow Meta [every question should have a top-level tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/frequently-asked-questions-about-tagging-on-mathoverflow#1076) In reality, the top-level tag is missing on [roughly 20% of questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49009859#49009859).

Answer (score 0):

There are tags [laplacian](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/laplacian) and [laplace-equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/laplace-equation). Neither has a wiki or guidelines for usage. The tag [laplacian](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/laplacian) seems to be more popular. Should these be merged?

Comment: Are these really the same?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but quite closely related. I no longer remember if they are used in distinct ways. I think adding tag wikis would be nice, if one chooses to not merge them.

Comment: Better provide numbers. [tag:laplacian]: 165 questions. [tag:laplace-equation]: 16 questions.

Comment: Laplace equation has a precise meaning, namely refers to a classical PDE (laplacian equals zero). I see no particular problem to keep it separate.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to merge [stable-homotopy](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/stable-homotopy) and [stable-homotopy-category](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/stable-homotopy-category).
The latter is used for the same types of questions as the former,
and most questions with the latter have little to do with the stable
homotopy category per se, as opposed to the model category or ∞-category of spectra.

Comment: The difference [tag:stable-homotopy-category] minus [tag:stable-homotopy] consists of 19 questions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/stable-homotopy-category+-stable-homotopy

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: And, for example, the first two questions have nothing to do with the homotopy category per se.

Comment: For context: [tag:stable-homotopy]: 342 questions; [tag:stable-homotopy-category]: 44 questions.