# Why are MO tags formatted as they are?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that some of the more frequently used MO tags are formatted according to a certain pattern, e.g.:

- nt.number-theory
- pr.probability
- lo.logic
- fa.functional-analysis

Why are the tags formatted like this? Are they shortcuts for user convenience?

Comment: On a related note, I believe it would make sense to tag http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075 as [tag:faq].

Comment: @EmilJeřábek an efficient way to make this suggestion, recently introduce by Willie Wong, is to  tag it [meta-tag:faq-proposed] (note: the tag dissapered already, but see http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1429/how-to-retag-such-that-migration-works for the process )

Comment: @quid: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The tags with a two-letter prefix are *exactly* those tags that correspond to a [math subject class on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/archive/math). They serve as top-level tags. As a rule, each question should have at least one of these top-level tags.

The formatting is mainly in place to distinguish them from usual tags; that it can be convenient is a side aspect, in particular, other tags of this form *must not* be created 'for convenience', they will be deleted as soon as they are noted.

---

A complete list of these tags (copied from François G. Dorais)

- [ag.algebraic-geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ag.algebraic-geometry)
- [at.algebraic-topology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/at.algebraic-topology)
- [ap.analysis-of-pdes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ap.analysis-of-pdes)
- [ct.category-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ct.category-theory)
- [ca.analysis-and-odes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ca.analysis-and-odes)
- [co.combinatorics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/co.combinatorics)
- [ac.commutative-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ac.commutative-algebra)
- [cv.complex-variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/cv.complex-variables)
- [dg.differential-geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/dg.differential-geometry)
- [ds.dynamical-systems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ds.dynamical-systems)
- [fa.functional-analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/fa.functional-analysis)
- [gm.general-mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gm.general-mathematics)
- [gn.general-topology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gn.general-topology)
- [gt.geometric-topology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gt.geometric-topology)
- [gr.group-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gr.group-theory)
- [ho.history-overview](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ho.history-overview)
- [it.information-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/it.information-theory)
- [kt.k-theory-homology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/kt.k-theory-homology)
- [lo.logic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/lo.logic)
- [mp.mathematical-physics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/mp.mathematical-physics)
- [mg.metric-geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/mg.metric-geometry)
- [nt.number-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/nt.number-theory)
- [na.numerical-analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/na.numerical-analysis)
- [oa.operator-algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/oa.operator-algebras)
- [oc.optimization-control](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/oc.optimization-control)
- [pr.probability](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/pr.probability)
- [qa.quantum-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/qa.quantum-algebra)
- [rt.representation-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/rt.representation-theory)
- [ra.rings-and-algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ra.rings-and-algebras)
- [sp.spectral-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/sp.spectral-theory)
- [st.statistics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/st.statistics)
- [sg.symplectic-geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/sg.symplectic-geometry)