# Why is the ‘mathematical logic’ tag spelt [lo.logic]?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

On MathOverflow, questions about mathematical logic bear the tag [lo.logic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/lo.logic), which has a synonym of [logic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/logic).

Where did this `lo.logic` spelling come from? Why is it not [logic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/logic) the primary spelling of the tag?

Comment: See here: [Why are MO tags formatted as they are?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1457) and [Frequently asked questions about tagging on MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075#1076)

Comment: just browsing most frequent tags you would have gotten some hints about this.