# Tag suggestions on ask page

Tags: feature-request, design, tags, user-interface

The [ask page](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/ask) tag input box currently looks like this:

[image: New Tag Box]

The old ask page on MO 1.0 had a much more detailed description of what top-level tags on MO are:

[image: Old Tag Box]

Since [appropriate tagging on MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/frequently-asked-questions-about-tagging-on-mathoverflow) can be confusing to new users, it would be great to reintroduce top-level tag suggestions on the ask page.

Comment: I'm taking a look at this, which means going back through a bit of history as changes go, and how your top tags are structured. Please give me a few days to wrap my head around all :)

Comment: Even if your proposal doesn't get implemented, maybe tag suggestions could help new users with the choice of tags: [Should MathOverflow request suggested tags feature?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3652)