# Should we flag suspected ChatGPT posts?

Tags: discussion, flagging

[Another meta question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5531/chatgpt-strikes-mathoverflow) raised the issue of AI-generated (by ChatGPT or similar) posts.

I have a more specific question. If we see a post that we suspect to be of this genre, would the moderators like us to flag it?

Comment: Yes, please. -- If you see such post, then please flag it and mention your suspicion.

Comment: Why flag ChatGPT posts (a type of plagiarism) but not other posts plagiarized (by memory) from standard textbooks?  Yes, I would like to a ChatGPT post so identified by the one posting it.  And similarly I would like proofs paraphrased from textbooks to have their source identified, even if it is just "I saw this back in graduate school".

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I thought the main problem with the ChatGPT posts was not so much plagiarism as that they are largely gibberish. OTOH, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "plagiarized (by memory)". It sounds really broad and easily misapplied.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Of course gibberish should be flagged however it was written.

Comment: I too don't see here any qualitative difference between ChatGPT gibberish and any other kind of gibberish. From my experience, it is out of the question that ChatGPT could be capable of disguising it in any way here. Maybe not in mathematics, maybe in near future, but not here and now. Until then, I don't think any special measures will be needed. Yes, I am aware that two of its answers have been accepted. I still do not see any qualitative difference from "ordinary" such situations, which also can happen.

Comment: Gerald Edgar's comment about plagiarism seems to envisage a situation in which ChatGPT's answer is so good that it's unethical to pass yourself off as being as mathematically competent as ChatGPT, when you aren't. That could be an issue in [poetry or art competitions](https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=6823) but it's not an issue on MathOverflow (yet!).

Comment: Has there ever been a post (answer or question) that is **correct** and reasonably concise but still has a ChatGPT feeling to it...?

Comment: @TimothyChow The upside would be that if one were to get sued, just consult the (surely upcoming) LawyerGPT

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question was answered in the comments, but just to underscore: the answer is *yes*. If you see a post you suspect is AI-written nonsense, flag it and describe your suspicion in the flag comment.

Comment: A small clarification: Should we flag them as “Very low quality” or “Needs moderator attention”, or are both OK?  (Personally I feel more comfortable using “very low quality”, since usually the fact it’s AI-based is just conjectural, whereas the fact it’s very low-quality is a judgement I’m much more confident in making.)

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Both are okay.

Comment: Choosing "needs moderator attention" does not commit you to a declaration that the post is AI-generated.

Comment: Does the flag remain even if the poster deletes their post? (I'm thinking of https://mathoverflow.net/a/437506/8133. Evidence for AI: language patterns, bizarre elementary mistake, citation to texts that don't exist, and the user has been banned at MSE for the same thing(!).)