# Suggestions for merging redundant tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't yet have the required reputation nor the answer-votes, yet I'd like to suggest identifying the tags
[isoperimetry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/isoperimetry) & [isoperimetric-problems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/isoperimetric-problems) with the (already synonymous) pair
[calculus-of-variations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/calculus-of-variations) & [variational-calculus](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/variational-calculus). All four tags seem perfectly equivalent. (Or maybe some discussion will show they are not?)
Likewise for [combinatorial-designs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/combinatorial-designs) and [design-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/design-theory).

Comment: The traditional way to get this done is to post an answer [here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/862/help-cleanup-tags). In any case, those clearly need cleanup. Any thoughts on which one to keep?

Comment: [tag:calculus-of-variations] and [tag:variational-calculus] are already synonyms.

Comment: Please ignore what the template says about your question.  I'm closing it so we can keep discussion about merging tags in one place.