# Tags "riemann-zeta-function" and "zeta-functions" are almost identical

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, retagging, tag-wikis

I have discovered that the following two tags are too similar to each other:

- [riemann-zeta-function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/riemann-zeta-function), with 299 questions tagged, has the description

> The Riemann zeta function is the function of one complex variable $s$ defined by the series $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^s}$ when $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 1$. It admits a meromorphic continuation to $\mathbb{C}$ with only a simple pole at $1$. This function satisfies a functional equation relating the values at $s$ and $1-s$. This is the most simple example of an $L$-function and a central object of number theory.

and no tag wiki;

- [zeta-functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/zeta-functions), with 195 questions tagged, has the description

> The Riemann zeta function is defined as the analytic continuation of the function defined for $\sigma > 1$ by the sum of the preceding series.

and tag wiki

> The Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(s)$, is a function of a complex variable $s$ that analytically continues the sum of the infinite series
>
> $$\zeta(s) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}$$
>
> which converges when the real part of $s$ is greater than $1$.

---

There are two problems here:

1. does it make sense to have one tag dedicated to just the Riemann $\zeta$, and a single other one for the rest of the $\zeta$ functions? A single tag for all these functions should suffice.
2. if we still want tags to distinguish between Riemann and "non-Riemann" $\zeta$ functions, then the latter class of functions should be correctly described in the tag description and tag wiki - a thing that does not currently happen with the latter tag.

My suggestion is to just melt the former tag into the latter, and automatically retag all the questions.

Comment: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/862/help-cleanup-tags/ gathers such requests (but possibly this 1-post big-list format is not optimal)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many interesting zeta functions, and the Riemann zeta function is the most notable of them.  It is natural to expect that people who ask questions about other zeta functions would want a separate tag, and indeed, only a very small proportion of the questions tagged [zeta-functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/zeta-functions) are about the Riemann zeta function.  I think it would be better to leave the tags separate and change the tag description for [zeta-functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/zeta-functions).

Update: I have [changed the tag description](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/236667/revisions).

Comment: There are Jacobi and Weierstrass zeta functioins also. They have nothing to do with Riemann zeta related functions. Perhaps a brief mention is appropriate to include in the tag description.