# What to do with the erdos tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This was [discussed before](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2094/should-we-create-an-erd%C5%91s-tag) but that discussion is outdated.

Tags related to a specific person are generally bad. (This is not the same as specific topics named after a person, e.g. Galois theory is not really about Évariste Galois.)  Some exceptions can still make sense, [Paul Erdős](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Erd%C5%91s) is certainly a strong candidate for such an exception.

Whether or not this is a good idea, the tag [erdos](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/erdos) does exist with 31 questions and no usage guidance.

What should we do with it:

- Leave as is? (And explain how it should be used!)
- Rename to `erdos-problems` or similar? Perhaps multiple related tags?
- Eliminate the tag entirely?

Comment: *Tags related to a specific person are generally bad* I suggest adding an argument as to why.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni There are several. For one, it would mostly be a meta-tag except for question about the person's life (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) for more info on meta-tags). I generally use some quick litmus tests to determine whether a tag is good or bad. The first test is: can I think of more than three contexts where one would search for this tag? The second test is: can I think of more than three people who might subscribe to notifications for this tag? This particular case fails the first but passes the second.

Comment: Can we get a hilbert tag?

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal, I don't know if there's room for a [tag:hilbert].

Comment: @LSpice, just move all the other tags up by one.

Answer (score 26):

In order to have something to vote on, I give @FrançoisG.Dorais's three suggestions as three separate answers.

3. Eliminate the tag entirely.

Comment: This one is my choice (I was surprised to see that the tag existed and had content!), but I can't vote for my own answer.

Comment: I voted for you.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Do you think that the voting suggests a strong enough consensus to start removing [tag:erdos]?
Would it be reasonable to start with the [17 questions that are not tagged co.combinatorics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/erdos+-co.combinatorics) and then asking mods to [remove the tag from the rest](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/erdos+co.combinatorics) by merging [tag:erdos] into [tag:combinatorics]?

Answer (score 11):

In order to have something to vote on, I give @FrançoisG.Dorais's three suggestions as three separate answers.

2. Rename to [erdos-problems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/erdos-problems) or similar. Perhaps multiple related tags.

Comment: If you vote for this option, please add your preferred rename(s) in a comment.

Comment: I think [tag:erdos-problem] would be a much better tag. The tag [tag:erdos] is a good illustration of "what's an example of a poor tag name?" Should I ask a question about a mathematical problem in which Erdős was involved, I wouldn't tag "erdos" because it's not a question about Erdős.

Answer (score 9):

In order to have something to vote on, I give @FrançoisG.Dorais's three suggestions as three separate answers.

1. Leave as is. (And explain how it should be used!)

Comment: If you vote for this option, please comment on how you think the tag should be used.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais, I guess a vote for this option together with no comment indicates that it should receive the empty use, i.e., none at all? 

Comment: I voted for this option just because I love Erdos! and I have no idea how the tag should be used. Just thought that seeing his name among the tags would be cool [insert shrug emoji]

Answer (score 7):

Just for the record, here are links to the 30 questions currently (Oct 18, 2022 18:20 GMT) tagged [erdos](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/erdos). Indeed, in case the tag is eliminated, this list might fail to be produceable.

The following 6 have no primary tag:

- [Happy ending problem - why not a proof by induction? (cont)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429884/),
- [When an Erdos-Renyi graph is locally tree like?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252055/),
- [Is there any published summary of Erdos's published problems in the American Mathematical Monthly journal?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280115/),
- [If Erdős is published as Erdös in a paper, which do I cite?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24585/)
- [mixing time of random walks on dense Erdos Renyi graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265781/),
- [Paul Erdős and Ramanujan Primes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73376/)

The other 24 (14 are tagged [co.combinatorics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/co.combinatorics), 12 [nt.number-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/nt.number-theory), 5 have both; 4 have [ho.history-overview](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ho.history-overview)):

- [List of problems that Erdős offered money for?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409088/),
- [Quasi-ideals and Erdős conjecture on arithmetic progressions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404886/),
- [Probabilistic bound to the number of edge disjoint triangles in a random graph](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390826/),
- [Updates on a least prime factor conjecture by Erdos](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368183/),
- [The Erdős-Turán conjecture or the Erdős' conjecture?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132648/),
- [Generalized Erdős multiplication table problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359501/),
- [The "core" of complete Erdős space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352788/),
- [Erdos distance problem n=12](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58203/),
- [Erdos Conjecture on arithmetic progressions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13230/),
- [Many representations as a sum of three squares](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217698/),
- [A reformulation of Erdős conjecture on arithmetic progressions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339427/),
- [Countable version of Erdös-Lovasz-Faber conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309901/),
- [How to find Erdős' treasure trove?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307209/),
- [Does there exist a comprehensive compilation of Erdos's open problems?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27716/),
- [Random graphs- Erdos and Renyi 1959 paper](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269899/),
- [On a relaxed form of Goldbach's conjecture proposed by Erdős](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269814/),
- [estimating binomial coefficients](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243171/),
- [What is the source of this E̶r̶d̶ő̶s̶ quote?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145475/),
- [A limit from an Erdos paper](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82491/),
- [A question about the number of intersections of lines in $R^{3}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61153/),
- [Degree reduction argument in Guth-Katz'sproof of Erdos distinct distance problem in the plane](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58718/),
- [Determining the vector space for application of Cauchy Schwarz](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56663/),
- [Did Erdős publish his proof of the multiplicative version of the Erdős-Turán conjecture?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49695/),
- [A limit involving the totient function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27625/)