# Why do we need the general-mathematics tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently came across the [general-mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gm.general-mathematics) tag. It has no usage guidelines, nor do I think it should exist. Do any of you know the historic reasons for its existence, or think it should stay as it is?

Amir

Comment: Math Overflow has tags corresponding to all of the Arxiv math subjects.  Including GM.

Comment: Some older (from 2013) discussion whether this tag should be deleted or not: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/642/tags-that-encourage-off-topic-questions/720#720