# Role of the tag "gm.general-mathematics"

Tags: discussion, on-topic, tags

This question is about the tag [gm.general-mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gm.general-mathematics). A meta question about it [already occurred](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3199/why-do-we-need-the-general-mathematics-tag) here, but was less specific (and didn't generate much discussion). See also the discussion in the comments of [this answer to the question *"tags which encourage off-topic questions"*](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/720/14094).

As a top-level tag, it is one of the of the arXiv math subjects. As an arXiv subject has a quite bad reputation, as it plays there some kind of trash role, e.g. to redirect unlikely proofs of fancy conjectures.

At MO I don't see the point to use it as a trash-tag, since we already have [tag-removed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/tag-removed) to retag randomly tagged highly off-topic questions. And for questions that are correctly tagged but off-topic, keeping the tag is essentially harmless or even helpful (e.g., I don't see the point to remove "[gr.group-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gr.group-theory)" to a question of beginner level in group theory, even keeping it can accelerate closure).

Back to my point, my suggestion would be to use the tag [gm.general-mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gm.general-mathematics) to questions where it literally applies, that is, whose field is not specific to any subfield of mathematics, but still includes some mathematical discussion (e.g., would apply to *"what is your favorite trick...?"* or *"examples of misleading widely use notation"*, rather than to *"Should I tell my adviser that I don't like my subject"* or *"Why does arXiv reject papers such that (...)"*). Thus would not be just a clone of [soft-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/soft-question). And I would find it quite useful in such a role, even if it will naturally have a ratio of off-topic questions higher than average.

What do you think?

Comment: So in short: use [tag:gm.general-mathematics] for mathematics questions which do not fall into a particular subfield of mathematics, and use [tag:soft-question] for questions interesting to mathematicians which are not mathematics questions?

Comment: @StefanKohl Roughly yes. [tag:soft-question] has a tag excerpt (*Questions that are about research in math, or about the job of a research mathematician, without being mathematical problems or statements in the strictest sense. Do not use this tag for easy or supposedly easy mathematical questions.*) which I find useful and its current use is OK. I guess the role of [tag:gm.general-mathematics] will remain a bit vague, but I especially want to exclude it as dedicated trash tag.

Comment: "*mathematics questions which do not fall into a particular subfield of mathematics*" could make a good tag excerpt. The current tag excerpt "*Questions about mathematics which don't fall into the other arXiv categories. If you have a general question about mathematics but it is not research level, it's off-topic but it might be welcomed on Mathematics Stack Exchange*" is quite bad, I think. Questions are usually redirected to MathSE because they're not of research level, not because they're about "general mathematics"; they are often focussed.

Comment: There is a recommendation that every question should have a top-level tag. (See: [Why are MO tags formatted as they are?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1457) and [Frequently asked questions about tagging on MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075#1076).) If we want to follow this recommendation, there will be many questions where this is the only suitable top-level tag. (There are many questions which are not tied to a specific area of mathematics, e.g., list of examples from various area, asking for advice, etc.)