# Is this post incompatible with its tags?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic, vote-to-close

Is the  following question incompatible  with its  tags? I really  do not understand the reason that some  participants  voted to closing this question as off topic question:

[PhD dissertations that solve an established open problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298600/phd-dissertations-that-solve-an-established-open-problem)

May I ask your  suggestion for  some  negative points of this  question?

If the  above  MO  question is  compatible  with its  tags, does all or  some of  its tags  satisfies the  following meta post?

[Tags that encourage off-topic questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/642/tags-that-encourage-off-topic-questions?rq=1)