# Remove [tag:slick-proof] or make it a synonym of [tag:alternative-proof]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

@YCor made a suggestion in an [answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4443) to another post ([What is the intended use of the (proofs) tag?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3844)) a bit over a year ago.  It received several upvotes, but does not appear to have been acted upon.  I thought it might receive more attention here:

> It's not exactly about the original question, but now [proofs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/proofs) has been duly removed. There are still the tags [alternative-proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/alternative-proof) and [slick-proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/slick-proof) (47 and 17 questions respectively at this date 2020/Feb/06). While in practice they have close meanings, the second one is unpleasantly non-neutral, and I'd like it to be removed, practically making it a synonym of [alternative-proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/alternative-proof) would sound fine. Or manually (**I'll understand upvotes/downvotes of this answer as for/against replacement of [slick-proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/slick-proof) with [alternative-proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/alternative-proof)**).

I tried proposing the tag synonym myself, but I do not have sufficient reputation.

Comment: An interesting thing about post titles:  it appears possible to use `[tag:xxx]` in the title when creating a post, but not when editing it.  I tried to edit https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4927/positive-characteristic-and-characteristic-p-are-synonyms accordingly, and was scolded by the software.

Comment: A related discussion in chat: [About (slick-proof) and (alternative-proof)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/conversation/about-slick-proof-and-alternative-proof).

Comment: Merged. All options here are "meta tags". Ideally, these would not exist at all. Can you imagine a MO user who is _systematically_ interested in _all_ alternative or _all_ slick proofs? I can't but in this case, I can imagine a MO user doing a one-time systematic search for alternative proofs but the tag alone will not fully capture all cases and the user should probably use another kind of filtering. In any case, that's enough for not deleting entirely.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais, could you post [that](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4942/remove-tagslick-proof-or-make-it-a-synonym-of-tagalternative-proof#comment25298_4942) as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Also, @FrançoisG.Dorais, since you have the capacity to make such actions yourself, would it be possible for you to approve the synonym [tag:characteristic-p] → [tag:positive-characteristic], as in https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4927/positive-characteristic-and-characteristic-p-are-synonyms?

Comment: I like the slick proofs tag... I and my grad student and postdoc friends enjoy looking at slick proofs outside our areas of concentration. Maybe not literally every one, but generally I like looking at cool tricks I can just learn.

Comment: I think that *everybody* (well, every mathematician) likes looking at slick proofs, but MO is not the place for collecting all things (not even all mathematical things) that are pleasant to look at; SE in general shies away from 'bloggy' content (although MO is different from SE generally in many ways, including this way sometimes).  Also, not to be too crude, I'm much more interested in the community's judgement of which proofs are slick than in any individual question-poser's judgement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been [done](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/alternative-proof/synonyms) (probably a long time ago, but I just noticed).

Comment: Actually, the moderator who created the synonym left a comment [at the time](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2021/3/28). (And you responded by asking him to post it as an answer.) Both [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1178483/data-about-a-tag-synonym?tagname=slick-proof) and the [list of tag synonyms](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/synonyms) say that it was created in March 2021 by François G. Dorais.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4942/remove-tagslick-proof-or-make-it-a-synonym-of-tagalternative-proof/5712#comment28861_5712), whoops!  Indeed, it is just as you say.  Thanks!